# ASP.Net MVC Intranet App keeps prmpting for credentials when running through IIS

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I'm trying to setup an ASP.Net MVC 4 Intranet app to use Windows Authentication.  It's working if I run the app through VisualStudio's Development Server.  However, if I try accessing the site via IIS 7, the user is always prompted for credentials.  Here's my WebConfig:

```
    <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I've also disabled ANonymous authentication and enabled Windows Authentication in IIS Manager.  What am I missing in order to make my site work through IIS?

Comment: Seems odd. Is IIS installed on your own machine?

Comment: In IIS, do you have basic authentication enabled? Or is the user perhaps using Firefox?

Comment: I'm using Firefox.  Basic Authentication is disabled.

Comment: I enabled Basic Authentication and tried the app in Chrome, and I still get prompted for credentials.

Comment: Try switching it from integrated to classic mode, or vise versa

Comment: Firefox doesn't support the passing of credentials without prompting on IIS (using integrated authentication) without extra setup. See: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris